# javascript send variable but insert array php not work propertly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have a problem with this code, in INSERT only insert the first item_price in every insert, in example i have three differents item_price,  thanks for you help sorry for bad english

html part in table:

```
<table>
<tr id="shop1">
<td>1</td> <!-- item_id -->
<td><input type="text" value="33" name="price"></td> <!-- item_price -->
</tr>
<tr id="shop2">
<td>2</td> <!-- item_id -->
<td><input type="text" value="11" name="price"></td> <!-- item_price -->
</tr>
<tr id="shop3">
<td>3</td> <!-- item_id -->
<td><input type="text" value="65" name="price"></td> <!-- item_price -->
</tr>
</table>
<button id="checkoutinventory" class="btn-danger"></button>
```

javascript part:

```
$(document).on("click","button#checkoutinventory, a[href$='checkoutinventory']",function()
    {
        var items = "";
        var price = "";

        $("tr[id^=shop] button.btn-danger").each(function()
        {
            items += $(this).parents("tr").attr("id").replace(/\D/g,'')+",";
            price += $(this).parents("tr").find('input[name="price"]').val().replace(/\D/g,'')+","; //this code send price in this format: 1,2,3,etc
        });

        if (!items)
            return displayResponse("ERROR","an error ocurred try again.");

        var settings = {};
        settings['action'] = "checkoutinventory";
        settings['items'] = items;
        settings['price'] = price;

        $.get("includes/process.php", settings, function(data)
        {
            processResponse(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
```

process.php part:

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "checkoutinventory")
    {
        if (!@$character)
            exit("REFRESH");

        if (!$VALIDATE->blank(@$_GET['items']))
            exit();

        $items = explode(",", rtrim($_GET['items'],",")); //Here obtain item_id in this format: id_1,id_2,id_3,etc
        $price = $_GET['price']; //Here obtain item_price in this format: price1,price2,price3,etc

        $isonline = $SERVER->select($query['characterIsonline'],array($COOKIE->get("character")));

        if(!$isonline)
        {
            $itemData = $SERVER->select("SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `object_id` IN (".implode(",",$items).");",array()); //Here obtain perfectly information for insert later in foreach
        } else {
            exit("RESPONSE^ERROR^Your character <b>".$character['char_name']."</b> is online disconnect please and try again..");
        }
        if($itemData) {
            foreach($itemData as $itemlist)
                {
                $selling = $SERVER->insert("INSERT INTO `shop_items` (`itemId`,`itemAmount`,`itemPrice`,`itemEnchant`,`vendedor`,`object_id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);",array($itemlist['item_id'],$itemlist['count'],$_GET['price'],$itemlist['enchant_level'],$character['char_name'],$itemlist['object_id']));
            }
        }

        if (count($items) != count($itemData))
            exit("RESPONSE^ERROR^One of the items is no longer available for sale.");

        if($selling) {
            exit("RESPONSE^SUCCESS^Congrats <b>".$character['char_name']."</b>, you sell ".count($items)." item(s)!");
            }

        exit("RESPONSE^ERROR^Unexpected error occured.");
    }
```

Comment: UPDATE explain sorry:
hi!, i have a problem with this code, in INSERT only insert the first item_price in every insert, in example i have three differents item_price,  thanks for you help sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you want to match the price to the item by position (i.e. 1st value in the price array belongs to the 1st value in the item array)

```
if($itemData) {
    $prices = explode(',',$price); //create an array of prices

    foreach($itemData as $itemlist) {

        $single_price = array_shift($prices); //remove the 1st price from array

        $selling = $SERVER->insert("INSERT INTO `shop_items` 
            (`itemId`,`itemAmount`,`itemPrice`,`itemEnchant`,`vendedor`,`object_id`) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);",
            array($itemlist['item_id'],$itemlist['count'],$single_price,$itemlist['enchant_level'],$character['char_name'],$itemlist['object_id']));
    }
}
```

Comment: @JulianAlbarracinCruz i don't understand your question then because i thought that's what you want

Comment: your fix work but insert in table duplicate records, see my answer

Comment: I've just seen updating your comment, this is solution! thanks very much :D
array_shift